# Unable to connect to MYSQL server database using pycharm community (2.7.11)

Tags: python, pycharm

I am not getting Database tool window under View-> Tool Windows, in pyhcharm community version software, so that I can connect to MYSQL server database. Also,please suggest me if there is other ways by which I can connect to MY SQL server database using pycharm community version.

Answer (score 1):

Database support available only in paid Jetbrains IDEs